# KnockoutJS hasFocus doesn't work

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, binding

I can't seem to figure out how to make this thing work, wherever i put this binding it won't work

Here's my script

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle expanded" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" data-bind="hasFocus:notificationService.aaaa">

this.aaaa = ko.observable(false);
```

And my html

```
<span data-bind="text:notificationService.aaaa"></span>
```

Where notificationService is an Object passed with Require. Everything else works, but not this hasFocus

Any clues?

Comment: Why do you have a `text` binding?

Comment: i forgot to upload the hasFocus, now it's on @JasonSpake

Comment: It looks like you're mixing bootstrap with knockout, which generally requires custom bindings to work since bootstrap removes the element from the DOM and replaces it with its own markup, and won't preserve your bindings.

Comment: Is the `aaaa` member an `observable`?

Comment: @JasonSpake i tried to remove all the bootstrap-related attributes, but nothing changed

Comment: @RoyJ Yes it is

Answer (score 1):

If `notificationService` is an `observable`, your binding needs to be

```
data-bind="hasFocus:notificationService().aaaa"
```

(with the invocation parentheses after `notificationService`). Also, you need to add `tabindex` to the `<a>` tag, as your anchor is not a link (it has no `href`) and so it would not normally be able to be focused.

```js
const vm = {
  notificationService: ko.observable({
    aaaa: ko.observable(false)
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(() => {
  vm.notificationService().aaaa(true);
}, 800);
```

```css
a:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<a class="dropdown-toggle expanded" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" data-bind="hasFocus:notificationService().aaaa" tabindex="0">Anchor</a>
<span data-bind="text:ko.toJSON(notificationService)"></span>
```